# Configuring the MPEG4MediaSink

Tags: c++, windows, ms-media-foundation

I am attempting to build a simple demonstration WMF application which uses a Media Source, Pipeline and Media Sink to copy an MP4 file. Here is the basic procedure

1. Create the media source, and get the presentation descriptor from it
2. Get the first active video and audio stream descriptors from the
       presentation descriptor
3. Get the current video and audio IMFMediaTypes from each stream
   descriptor. A check indicates that the video media sub type is H264
   and the audio media sub type is AAC
4. Open up the media sink using MFCreateMPEG4MediaSink, the two media
   types and an output filename.
5. Set up the video and audio source nodes using the stream and
   presentation descriptors
6. Set up the video and audio sink nodes using the media sink.
7. Add all the nodes to the topology
8. Connect the source nodes to the sink nodes
9. Build the topology and run.

The error I get is MF_E_INVALIDMEDIATYPE in my Media Session call back. If I comment out the audio stream, feed a null into MFCreateMPEG4MediaSink call for the audio type and do not set up any nodes for it then the copy works fine – I can play the resulting mp4 file which has video only.

The MPEG4MediaSink is supposed to be able to handle AAC audio. However I suspect there is something in the media type that it does not like (remember it is directly derived from the source stream without changes).

I would appreciate any insights or suggestions into what might need to be done to get the audio stream working.

I have successfully done a similar sort of copy with an MP3 file using the MFCreateMP3MediaSink – but the media type in that case was MP3.

Comment: Run your app using mftrace.exe. Very likely, it’ll tell you exactly why are you getting MF_E_INVALIDMEDIATYPE error.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/medfound/using-mftrace
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/mf/2010/08/11/using-mftrace-to-trace-media-foundation/

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion but I don't think that is an option in my case. I am using WMF.net and C#. I don't think this is a WMF.net issue though - numerous C++ examples I have adapted seems to work fine. I am on my own here regarding the configuration of the mp4 file sink though. There doesn't seem to be a lot of information about configuring it - most examples just use the sink to create a sink writer and then use that.

Comment: It doesn’t matter which language are you using. Just build a version that tries to set that AAC audio stream and fails, run it using mftrace.exe, and read the log.

Comment: Thanks. I have been trying to do that. I am on Windows 10 and the SDK for that version does not seem to have mftrace.exe. The windows 7 sdk apparently will not install without (what looks like) a series of painful manual edits to the registry. Sorry to be a pain about this but are you on Windows 10? If so how did you get mftrace installed?

Comment: Yes I’m on Win10. No I haven’t installed anything, it’s part of Windows SDK so I have 22 different versions of the tool already installed, all of them are under `C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits`.

Comment: You probably need one from the latest version of Win10 SDK (C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\bin\10.0.17134.0 on my PC), x86 or x64 depending on how you’re building your software.

Answer (score 1):

just for fun, i rewrote your program in a quickly way :

```
//----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Main.cpp
//----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
#pragma once
#define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN
#define STRICT

#pragma comment(lib, "mf")
#pragma comment(lib, "mfplat")
#pragma comment(lib, "mfuuid")

#include <WinSDKVer.h>
#include <new>
#include <windows.h>

#include <mfapi.h>
#include <mfidl.h>
#include <wchar.h>

#define MP4_SOURCE_VIDEO_MEDIA_FILE L"big_buck_bunny_720p_50mb.mp4"
#define MP4_FINAL_VIDEO_MEDIA_FILE L"final.mp4"

HRESULT ProcessConverter(LPCWSTR);
HRESULT ConfigureSource(LPCWSTR, IMFMediaSource**, IMFMediaType**, IMFMediaType**, IMFTopologyNode**, IMFTopologyNode**);
HRESULT CreateMediaSource(LPCWSTR, IMFMediaSource**);
HRESULT ConfigureMediaTypeSource(IMFMediaSource*, IMFPresentationDescriptor*, IMFStreamDescriptor*, IMFMediaType**, IMFMediaType**, IMFTopologyNode**, IMFTopologyNode**);
HRESULT CreateTopologyNodeSink(IMFMediaSink*, IMFTopologyNode**, IMFTopologyNode**, IMFMediaType*, IMFMediaType*);
HRESULT CreateSourceStreamNode(IMFMediaSource*, IMFPresentationDescriptor*, IMFStreamDescriptor*, IMFTopologyNode**);
HRESULT ConfigureSinkNode(IMFMediaTypeHandler*, IMFStreamSink*, IMFTopologyNode**, IMFMediaType*);
HRESULT ConfigureTopologyNode(IMFTopology*, IMFTopologyNode*, IMFTopologyNode*, IMFTopologyNode*, IMFTopologyNode*);
HRESULT RunMediaSession(IMFMediaSession*);

template <class T> inline void SAFE_RELEASE(T*& p){

    if(p){
        p->Release();
        p = NULL;
    }
}

void main() {

    HRESULT hr = CoInitializeEx(NULL, COINIT_APARTMENTTHREADED | COINIT_DISABLE_OLE1DDE);

    if(SUCCEEDED(hr)) {

        hr = MFStartup(MF_VERSION, MFSTARTUP_LITE);

        if(SUCCEEDED(hr)) {

            hr = ProcessConverter(MP4_SOURCE_VIDEO_MEDIA_FILE);

            hr = MFShutdown();
        }

        CoUninitialize();
    }
}

HRESULT ProcessConverter(LPCWSTR wszVideoFile){

    HRESULT hr = S_OK;
    IMFMediaSource* pSource = NULL;
    IMFMediaType* pVideoMediaType = NULL;
    IMFMediaType* pAudioMediaType = NULL;
    IMFByteStream* pByteStream = NULL;
    IMFMediaSink* pMediaSink = NULL;
    IMFTopology* pTopology = NULL;
    IMFTopologyNode* pVideoSourceNode = NULL;
    IMFTopologyNode* pAudioSourceNode = NULL;
    IMFTopologyNode* pVideoSinkNode = NULL;
    IMFTopologyNode* pAudioSinkNode = NULL;
    IMFMediaSession* pSession = NULL;

    hr = MFCreateFile(MF_ACCESSMODE_WRITE, MF_OPENMODE_DELETE_IF_EXIST, MF_FILEFLAGS_NONE, MP4_FINAL_VIDEO_MEDIA_FILE, &pByteStream);

    if(FAILED(hr)){ goto done; }

    hr = ConfigureSource(wszVideoFile, &pSource, &pVideoMediaType, &pAudioMediaType, &pVideoSourceNode, &pAudioSourceNode);

    if(FAILED(hr)){ goto done; }

    hr = MFCreateMPEG4MediaSink(pByteStream, pVideoMediaType, pAudioMediaType, &pMediaSink);

    if(FAILED(hr)){ goto done; }

    hr = CreateTopologyNodeSink(pMediaSink, &pVideoSinkNode, &pAudioSinkNode, pVideoMediaType, pAudioMediaType);

    if(FAILED(hr)){ goto done; }

    hr = MFCreateTopology(&pTopology);

    if(FAILED(hr)){ goto done; }

    hr = ConfigureTopologyNode(pTopology, pVideoSourceNode, pAudioSourceNode, pVideoSinkNode, pAudioSinkNode);

    if(FAILED(hr)){ goto done; }

    hr = MFCreateMediaSession(NULL, &pSession);

    if(FAILED(hr)){ goto done; }

    hr = pSession->SetTopology(0, pTopology);

    if(FAILED(hr)){ goto done; }

    hr = RunMediaSession(pSession);

done:

    if(pSession){

        hr = pSession->Close();

        // todo : normally wait for close event, here just Sleep
        Sleep(1000);
    }

    if(pMediaSink){

        hr = pMediaSink->Shutdown();
        SAFE_RELEASE(pMediaSink);
    }

    if(pSource){

        hr = pSource->Shutdown();
        SAFE_RELEASE(pSource);
    }

    if(pSession){

        hr = pSession->Shutdown();
        SAFE_RELEASE(pSession);
    }

    SAFE_RELEASE(pByteStream);
    SAFE_RELEASE(pAudioMediaType);
    SAFE_RELEASE(pVideoMediaType);

    SAFE_RELEASE(pAudioSinkNode);
    SAFE_RELEASE(pVideoSinkNode);
    SAFE_RELEASE(pAudioSourceNode);
    SAFE_RELEASE(pVideoSourceNode);

    SAFE_RELEASE(pTopology);

    return hr;
}

HRESULT ConfigureSource(LPCWSTR wszVideoFile, IMFMediaSource** ppSource, IMFMediaType** ppVideoMediaType, IMFMediaType** ppAudioMediaType, IMFTopologyNode** ppVideoSourceNode, IMFTopologyNode** ppVAudioSourceNode){

    HRESULT hr = S_OK;
    IMFPresentationDescriptor* pPresentationDescriptor = NULL;
    IMFStreamDescriptor* pStreamDescriptor = NULL;
    DWORD dwStreamCount = 0;
    BOOL bSelected = FALSE;

    hr = CreateMediaSource(wszVideoFile, ppSource);

    if(FAILED(hr)){ goto done; }

    hr = (*ppSource)->CreatePresentationDescriptor(&pPresentationDescriptor);

    if(FAILED(hr)){ goto done; }

    hr = pPresentationDescriptor->GetStreamDescriptorCount(&dwStreamCount);

    if(FAILED(hr)){ goto done; }

    for(DWORD dwStream = 0; dwStream < dwStreamCount; dwStream++){

        hr = pPresentationDescriptor->GetStreamDescriptorByIndex(dwStream, &bSelected, &pStreamDescriptor);

        if(FAILED(hr)){
            break;
        }

        if(bSelected){

            hr = ConfigureMediaTypeSource(*ppSource, pPresentationDescriptor, pStreamDescriptor, ppVideoMediaType, ppAudioMediaType, ppVideoSourceNode, ppVAudioSourceNode);
        }

        SAFE_RELEASE(pStreamDescriptor);

        if(FAILED(hr) || ((*ppVideoMediaType) && (*ppAudioMediaType))){
            break;
        }
    }

done:

    SAFE_RELEASE(pStreamDescriptor);
    SAFE_RELEASE(pPresentationDescriptor);

    // We just only if video and audio stream are presents
    if((*ppVideoMediaType) == NULL && (*ppAudioMediaType) == NULL)
        hr = E_FAIL;

    return hr;
}

HRESULT CreateMediaSource(LPCWSTR wszVideoFile, IMFMediaSource** ppSource){

    MF_OBJECT_TYPE ObjectType = MF_OBJECT_INVALID;

    IMFSourceResolver* pSourceResolver = NULL;
    IUnknown* pSource = NULL;

    HRESULT hr = MFCreateSourceResolver(&pSourceResolver);

    if(FAILED(hr)){ goto done; }

    hr = pSourceResolver->CreateObjectFromURL(wszVideoFile, MF_RESOLUTION_MEDIASOURCE, NULL, &ObjectType, &pSource);

    if(FAILED(hr)){ goto done; }

    hr = pSource->QueryInterface(IID_PPV_ARGS(ppSource));

done:

    SAFE_RELEASE(pSourceResolver);
    SAFE_RELEASE(pSource);

    return hr;
}

HRESULT ConfigureMediaTypeSource(IMFMediaSource* pSource, IMFPresentationDescriptor* pPresentationDescriptor, IMFStreamDescriptor* pStreamDescriptor, IMFMediaType** ppVideoMediaType,
    IMFMediaType** ppAudioMediaType, IMFTopologyNode** ppVideoSourceNode, IMFTopologyNode** ppAudioSourceNode){

    HRESULT hr = S_OK;
    IMFMediaTypeHandler* pHandler = NULL;
    IMFMediaType* pMediaType = NULL;
    DWORD dwTypeCount = 0;
    GUID MajorType = GUID_NULL;

    hr = pStreamDescriptor->GetMediaTypeHandler(&pHandler);

    if(FAILED(hr)){ goto done; }

    hr = pHandler->GetMediaTypeCount(&dwTypeCount);

    if(FAILED(hr)){ goto done; }

    for(DWORD dwType = 0; dwType < dwTypeCount; dwType++){

        hr = pHandler->GetMediaTypeByIndex(dwType, &pMediaType);

        if(hr == S_OK){

            hr = pMediaType->GetMajorType(&MajorType);

            if(hr == S_OK){

                if(MajorType == MFMediaType_Video && (*ppVideoMediaType) == NULL){

                    hr = pHandler->SetCurrentMediaType(pMediaType);

                    if(hr == S_OK){

                        //LogMediaType(pMediaType);

                        hr = CreateSourceStreamNode(pSource, pPresentationDescriptor, pStreamDescriptor, ppVideoSourceNode);

                        if(hr == S_OK){
                            *ppVideoMediaType = pMediaType;
                            (*ppVideoMediaType)->AddRef();
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }
                else if(MajorType == MFMediaType_Audio && (*ppAudioMediaType) == NULL){

                    hr = pHandler->SetCurrentMediaType(pMediaType);

                    if(hr == S_OK){

                        //LogMediaType(pMediaType);

                        hr = CreateSourceStreamNode(pSource, pPresentationDescriptor, pStreamDescriptor, ppAudioSourceNode);

                        if(hr == S_OK){
                            *ppAudioMediaType = pMediaType;
                            (*ppAudioMediaType)->AddRef();
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        SAFE_RELEASE(pMediaType);
    }

done:

    SAFE_RELEASE(pMediaType);
    SAFE_RELEASE(pHandler);

    return hr;
}

HRESULT CreateSourceStreamNode(IMFMediaSource* pSource, IMFPresentationDescriptor* pPresentationDescriptor, IMFStreamDescriptor* pStreamDescriptor, IMFTopologyNode** ppNode){

    HRESULT hr = S_OK;
    IMFTopologyNode* pNode = NULL;

    hr = MFCreateTopologyNode(MF_TOPOLOGY_SOURCESTREAM_NODE, &pNode);

    if(FAILED(hr)){ goto done; }

    hr = pNode->SetUnknown(MF_TOPONODE_SOURCE, pSource);

    if(FAILED(hr)){ goto done; }

    hr = pNode->SetUnknown(MF_TOPONODE_PRESENTATION_DESCRIPTOR, pPresentationDescriptor);

    if(FAILED(hr)){ goto done; }

    hr = pNode->SetUnknown(MF_TOPONODE_STREAM_DESCRIPTOR, pStreamDescriptor);

    if(FAILED(hr)){ goto done; }

    *ppNode = pNode;
    (*ppNode)->AddRef();

done:

    SAFE_RELEASE(pNode);

    return hr;
}

HRESULT CreateTopologyNodeSink(IMFMediaSink* pMediaSink, IMFTopologyNode** ppVideoSinkNode, IMFTopologyNode** ppAudioSinkNode, IMFMediaType* pVideoMediaType, IMFMediaType* pAudioMediaType){

    HRESULT hr = S_OK;
    DWORD dwCount = 0;
    IMFStreamSink* pStreamSink = NULL;
    IMFMediaTypeHandler* pHandler = NULL;
    GUID MajorType = GUID_NULL;

    hr = pMediaSink->GetStreamSinkCount(&dwCount);

    if(FAILED(hr)){ goto done; }

    for(DWORD dwIndex = 0; dwIndex < dwCount; dwIndex++){

        hr = pMediaSink->GetStreamSinkByIndex(dwIndex, &pStreamSink);

        if(hr == S_OK){

            hr = pStreamSink->GetMediaTypeHandler(&pHandler);

            if(hr == S_OK){

                hr = pHandler->GetMajorType(&MajorType);

                if(hr == S_OK){

                    if(MajorType == MFMediaType_Video)
                        hr = ConfigureSinkNode(pHandler, pStreamSink, ppVideoSinkNode, pVideoMediaType);
                    else if(MajorType == MFMediaType_Audio)
                        hr = ConfigureSinkNode(pHandler, pStreamSink, ppAudioSinkNode, pAudioMediaType);
                }

                if(hr == S_OK && (*ppVideoSinkNode) != NULL && (*ppAudioSinkNode) != NULL){
                    break;
                }
            }

            SAFE_RELEASE(pHandler);
        }

        SAFE_RELEASE(pStreamSink);
    }

done:

    SAFE_RELEASE(pHandler);
    SAFE_RELEASE(pStreamSink);

    if((*ppVideoSinkNode) == NULL || (*ppAudioSinkNode) == NULL)
            hr = E_FAIL;

    return hr;
}

HRESULT ConfigureSinkNode(IMFMediaTypeHandler* pHandler, IMFStreamSink* pStreamSink, IMFTopologyNode** ppSinkNode, IMFMediaType* pMediaType){

    HRESULT hr = S_OK;
    IMFTopologyNode* pNode = NULL;

    hr = pHandler->SetCurrentMediaType(pMediaType);

    if(FAILED(hr)){ goto done; }

    hr = MFCreateTopologyNode(MF_TOPOLOGY_OUTPUT_NODE, &pNode);

    if(FAILED(hr)){ goto done; }

    hr = pNode->SetObject(pStreamSink);

    if(FAILED(hr)){ goto done; }

    *ppSinkNode = pNode;
    (*ppSinkNode)->AddRef();

done:

    SAFE_RELEASE(pNode);

    return hr;
}

HRESULT ConfigureTopologyNode(IMFTopology* pTopology, IMFTopologyNode* pVideoSourceNode, IMFTopologyNode* pAudioSourceNode, IMFTopologyNode* pVideoSinkNode, IMFTopologyNode* pAudioSinkNode){

    HRESULT hr = S_OK;

    hr = pTopology->AddNode(pVideoSourceNode);

    if(FAILED(hr)){ goto done; }

    hr = pTopology->AddNode(pAudioSourceNode);

    if(FAILED(hr)){ goto done; }

    hr = pTopology->AddNode(pVideoSinkNode);

    if(FAILED(hr)){ goto done; }

    hr = pTopology->AddNode(pAudioSinkNode);

    if(FAILED(hr)){ goto done; }

    hr = pVideoSourceNode->ConnectOutput(0, pVideoSinkNode, 0);

    if(FAILED(hr)){ goto done; }

    hr = pAudioSourceNode->ConnectOutput(0, pAudioSinkNode, 0);

done:

    return hr;
}

HRESULT RunMediaSession(IMFMediaSession* pSession){

    HRESULT hr = S_OK;

    BOOL bSessionEvent = TRUE;

    while(bSessionEvent){

        HRESULT hrStatus = S_OK;
        IMFMediaEvent* pEvent = NULL;
        MediaEventType meType = MEUnknown;

        MF_TOPOSTATUS TopoStatus = MF_TOPOSTATUS_INVALID;

        hr = pSession->GetEvent(0, &pEvent);

        if(SUCCEEDED(hr)){
            hr = pEvent->GetStatus(&hrStatus);
        }

        if(SUCCEEDED(hr)){
            hr = pEvent->GetType(&meType);
        }

        if(SUCCEEDED(hr) && SUCCEEDED(hrStatus)){

            switch(meType){

                case MESessionTopologySet:
                    wprintf(L"MESessionTopologySet\n");
                    break;

                case MESessionTopologyStatus:

                    hr = pEvent->GetUINT32(MF_EVENT_TOPOLOGY_STATUS, (UINT32*)&TopoStatus);

                    if(SUCCEEDED(hr)){

                        switch(TopoStatus){

                            case MF_TOPOSTATUS_READY:
                            {
                                wprintf(L"MESessionTopologyStatus: MF_TOPOSTATUS_READY\n");
                                PROPVARIANT varStartPosition;
                                PropVariantInit(&varStartPosition);
                                hr = pSession->Start(&GUID_NULL, &varStartPosition);
                                PropVariantClear(&varStartPosition);
                            }
                            break;

                            case MF_TOPOSTATUS_STARTED_SOURCE:
                                wprintf(L"MESessionTopologyStatus: MF_TOPOSTATUS_STARTED_SOURCE\n");
                                break;

                            case MF_TOPOSTATUS_ENDED:
                                wprintf(L"MESessionTopologyStatus: MF_TOPOSTATUS_ENDED\n");
                                break;

                            default:
                                wprintf(L"MESessionTopologyStatus: %d\n", TopoStatus);
                                break;
                        }
                    }
                    break;

                case MESessionStarted:
                    wprintf(L"MESessionStarted\n");
                    break;

                case MESessionEnded:
                    wprintf(L"MESessionEnded\n");
                    hr = pSession->Stop();
                    break;

                case MESessionStopped:
                    wprintf(L"MESessionStopped\n");
                    hr = pSession->Close();
                    break;

                case MESessionClosed:
                    wprintf(L"MESessionClosed\n");
                    bSessionEvent = FALSE;
                    break;

                case MESessionNotifyPresentationTime:
                    wprintf(L"MESessionNotifyPresentationTime\n");
                    break;

                case MESessionCapabilitiesChanged:
                    wprintf(L"MESessionCapabilitiesChanged\n");
                    break;

                case MEEndOfPresentation:
                    wprintf(L"MEEndOfPresentation\n");
                    break;

                default:
                    wprintf(L"Media session event: %d\n", meType);
                    break;
            }

            SAFE_RELEASE(pEvent);

            if(FAILED(hr) || FAILED(hrStatus)){
                bSessionEvent = FALSE;
            }
        }
    }

    return hr;
}
```

Comment: This is great! - simple and linear and ideal for learning from. Thank you for posting it. I am gratified to find that it is almost identical in structure to my C# version. The more of this sort of sample code we can make available the better IMHO. I will be making my code available on github probably by mid-october. I am in the process of writing a (free) book on WMF targeted at the novice and a suite of sample code to go along with it.

Comment: I will put all sample code i wrote for stackoverflow on github, also MFNode project and others.  If you want me to take an eye on your book to emit an opinion, i will be glad to do it, even if it is C#, :-)

Comment: Thanks! I would love to have knowledgeable people take a look at it. The book is intended for the reasonably competent C# programmer who has not done much with either WMF or COM (i.e. me). It is a "get started" book. As I went about learning WMF I wrote down all the things that were not at all clear to me. I'm about 120 pages in and expect it will run to about 200 or so before it is done. There is plenty of background discussion which would be useful to the C++ programmer in that situation. The book will be available free and I hope to have it out the door in mid October.

Comment: There is also a suite of sample code. I'll get in touch with you when I have something presentable - I would value the feedback. Is the best way to send a message to you via your SourceForge account?

Comment: I create repo Github : https://github.com/mofo7777. Perhaps you can send message to github account, or open a stackoverflow chat.

Answer (score 0):

From Mediafoundation samples, you have LogMediaType function [LogMediaType](https://github.com/pauldotknopf/WindowsSDK7-Samples/blob/master/multimedia/mediafoundation/common/logmediatype.h)

Can you show us the MediaType log for AAC audio.

Typically, here is some attributes needed for AAC (some values may varie) :

- MF_MT_MAJOR_TYPE : MFMediaType_Audio
- MF_MT_SUBTYPE : MFAudioFormat_AAC or MEDIASUBTYPE_RAW_AAC1
- MF_MT_AUDIO_PREFER_WAVEFORMATEX : true
- MF_MT_AAC_PAYLOAD_TYPE : 0
- MF_MT_AAC_AUDIO_PROFILE_LEVEL_INDICATION : 0
- MF_MT_AUDIO_NUM_CHANNELS : 6
- MF_MT_AUDIO_SAMPLES_PER_SECOND : 48000
- MF_MT_AUDIO_BLOCK_ALIGNMENT : 24
- MF_MT_AUDIO_AVG_BYTES_PER_SECOND : 1152000
- MF_MT_AUDIO_BITS_PER_SAMPLE : 32
- MF_MT_AUDIO_CHANNEL_MASK : 63
- MF_MT_USER_DATA : byte array == AudioSpecificConfig (depends on MFAudioFormat_AAC or MEDIASUBTYPE_RAW_AAC1)

From SourceResolver, you could also see those attributes :

- MF_MT_MPEG4_SAMPLE_DESCRIPTION : byte array
- MF_MT_MPEG4_CURRENT_SAMPLE_ENTRY : 0
- MF_MT_AVG_BITRATE : x
- MF_MT_AM_FORMAT_TYPE : clsid
- MF_MT_ALL_SAMPLES_INDEPENDENT : 1
- MF_MT_FIXED_SIZE_SAMPLES : 1
- MF_MT_SAMPLE_SIZE : 1

The MF_MT_USER_DATA is very important when using objects provided by Microsoft. If some attributes are missing, try to add them manually.

**EDIT1**

Do you connect the audio source node to the right IMFStreamSink. Do you use the correct index from the IMFMediaSink ?

Comment: Thank you very much for this. Your edit turned out turned out to be the key. The problem was not in the Media Type - it was in the index on the media sink. I have provided more details below.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for the help!! The problem in this case was that a hard coded stream index of 0 was used when creating an output node. In my defence, the various WMF samples only seem to demonstrate one stream per sink and so use a hardcoded stream index of 0. I am basing my code on those examples and had factored that section out into a utility library and promptly forgot it was a special case. The MP4 sink, of course, uses two streams and the usage of the stream index of 0 for the audio broke when the topology was resolved.

For the record (in the thought that it might be useful to others) here is the setup of my Audio Media Type. This media type configuration works just fine once I sorted the streamsink issue These are broken down into the items that are the same, different, extra and missing from the above example audio media type content.

**The same**

```
MF_MT_MAJOR_TYPE=MFMediaType_Audio (73647561-0000-0010-8000-00aa00389b71)
MF_MT_SUBTYPE=AAC (00001610-0000-0010-8000-00aa00389b71)
MF_MT_AUDIO_PREFER_WAVEFORMATEX=1
MF_MT_AAC_PAYLOAD_TYPE=0
MF_MT_AAC_AUDIO_PROFILE_LEVEL_INDICATION=0
MF_MT_AUDIO_NUM_CHANNELS=6
MF_MT_AUDIO_SAMPLES_PER_SECOND=48000
```

**Different**

```
MF_MT_AUDIO_BLOCK_ALIGNMENT=1
MF_MT_AUDIO_AVG_BYTES_PER_SECOND=47995
MF_MT_AUDIO_BITS_PER_SAMPLE=16
```

**Unknown**

```
MF_MT_USER_DATA=00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,11,b0
```

**Extra**

```
MF_MT_AVG_BITRATE=383960
MF_MT_MPEG4_SAMPLE_DESCRIPTION=00,00,00,67,73,74,73,64,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,01...
MF_MT_AM_FORMAT_TYPE=Unknown (05589f81-c356-11ce-bf01-00aa0055595a)
MF_MT_MPEG4_CURRENT_SAMPLE_ENTRY=0
MF_MT_FIXED_SIZE_SAMPLES=1
MF_MT_ALL_SAMPLES_INDEPENDENT=1
MF_MT_SAMPLE_SIZE=1
```

**Missing**

```
MF_MT_AUDIO_CHANNEL_MASK : 63
```